# Can not lift multiple parameters in a monad

Tags: haskell, monads, lift, monoids

Hello i am trying to do the following:

```
module MyMonad where
f::(Monad m),=>m (a->b->c)->m a -> m b -> m c
f mf ma mb=
    ma >>= \a ->
    mb >>= \b ->
    mf >>= \c ->
        return (c a b)
```

and use it like this :

```
f (Just 3) (Just 4)
```

And i get the following error:

```
* Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> b -> c)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a b c.
              (Num a, Num (a -> b -> c)) =>
              Maybe b -> Maybe c
```

I didn't know how to put multiple type constraints so i tried like this:
`f (Just [3]) (Just [4]) (++)` -- (knowing `(++)` can be applied to any type - being a `monoid`).

 
In this case i get the following exception:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Maybe b0'
                  with actual type `[a1] -> [a1] -> [a1]'
    * Probable cause: `(++)' is applied to too few arguments
      In the third argument of `f', namely `(++)'
      In the expression: f (Just [3]) (Left [3]) (++)
      In an equation for `it': it = f (Just [3]) (Left [3]) (++)
```

Comment: *List types* are monoids; `Maybe a` is not. You still need to lift `(++)` to apply it to `Maybe` lists.

Comment: Note that you don't even need `m` to be a monad; an applicative would suffice. `f :: Applicative g => g (a -> b -> c) -> g a -> g b -> g c` with `f gf ga gb = gf <*> ga <*> gb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` requires a monad-wrapped function as the *first* argument. In your first try, you didn't pass the function at all; in the second, you pass `(++)` as the *last* argument.

The following works fine:

```
> f (Just (++)) (Just [3]) (Just [4])
Just [3,4]
```

`liftM2` (and more generally `liftA2`) already does something very similar to what you want.

```
> import Control.Monad (liftM2)
> liftM2 (++) (Just [3]) (Just [4])
Just [3,4]
> import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
> liftA2 (++) (Just [3]) (Just [4])
Just [3,4]
```

Comment: But could it not work with different types of functors? like `f (Just (++)) (Just [3]) (Left [4])`

Comment: No; I think that was a typo in the question. The given type requires the same monad throughout.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's your question, so it's not a typo. If you want to operate on values from two different monads, you need something like `(Monad m1, Monad m2) => (a -> b -> c) -> m1 a -> m2 b -> ???`. You'll have to decide which monad the result will live in. However, I don't recommend this. Let the caller be responsible for converting `Just [3]` to an `Either a b` value or `Left [4]` to a `Maybe a` value, and keep your function tied to a single monad. (For that matter, I would consider using `liftA2 (++) (Just [3]) (Just [4])` instead of manually lifting `(++)` before calling `f`.)